# Excel VBA Issues with portrait mode pictures AddPicture

Tags: image, vba, excel

I am having issues with inserting a picture in portrait mode using VBA.  If the picture is in landscape mode, then the picture is inserted into the associated shape in column B.  However, if the picture is in portrait, then the picture is offset 25 columns to column AA.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Sub cmdInsert1_Click()

Dim myPicture As String, MyObj As Object

Range("b5").Select

myPicture = Application.GetOpenFilename("Pictures (*.gif; *.jpg; *.bmp; *.tif),*.gif; *.jpg; *.bmp; *.tif", , "Select Picture to Import")

If myPicture = "False" Then Exit Sub

Set MyObj = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(myPicture, False, True, Range("B5").Left, Range("B5").Top, -1, -1)

With MyObj
    .Height = 293
    .Locked = False
End With

Set MyObj = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows "remembers" the orientation of the picture, so what is in the Top Left corner of your screen may not actually be the Top Left corner of the picture. You will need to check the `.Rotation` property of your picture. If it's rotated (ie, not 0), you will need to adjust your code accordingly. For example:

```
If myObj.Rotation = 0 Or myObj.Rotation = 180 Then 
    .Height = 293
Else
    .Width = 293
End If
```

Edit: Forgot to account for it merely being upside down